# How to rename the column of an intermediate result?

Tags: pandas

I'm calculating an average by first getting the number of of months and then divide the number of records by that number like this:

```
monthly = tables[SUB_ACCT_DOC_ACC_MTHLY_SUM]

num_months = monthly.clndr_yr_month.unique().size

df = (monthly[["sub_acct_id", "clndr_yr_month"]].groupby(["sub_acct_id"]).size() / num_months).reset_index("sub_acct_id")

df.head(5)
```

What I get is

```
    sub_acct_id  0
0   12716D       242.0
1   12716G       241.5
2   12716K       165.0
3   12716N       92.5
4   12716R       156.5
```

but how can I rename the new column to e.g. "*avg*"

```
    sub_acct_id  avg
0   12716D       242.0
1   12716G       241.5
2   12716K       165.0
3   12716N       92.5
4   12716R       156.5
```

Comment: `df.rename(columns={0:'avg'}, inplace=True)` should work

Answer (score 0):

You can access the names with the `columns` attribute of the dataframe:

```
df.columns = ['sub_acct_id','avg']
```